# How to save Date type data as string with format "dd-MM-yyyy" in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, date, format

The Sqlite normal `date` string format is `yyyy-MM-dd`.  How can I save it as `dd/MM/yyyy`?  Should I keep the `yyyy-MM-dd` format when working with the database and use `dd/MM/yyyy` only with the end user interface?
Edit 1:
I want to save my date datas as 'dd/MM/yyyy' in SQLite to be the same as my locale date format. But the date comparison is return wrong result with this format. I changed the date string in DB to 'yyyy-MM-dd' and the date comparison work perfect. Is 'yyyy-MM-dd' is the only string format which SQLite can understand as date?

Comment: Please review the answers given below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `strftime()` function which accepts as its first parameter a format string:

```
SELECT strftime('%d/%m/%Y', 'now');
```

**Output:**

```
06/10/2015
```

The `strftime()` function gives the ability to convert `Y-m-d` into `d/m/Y` or any other format you want.  So you can continue to store your date data as is in the database, and you can query it out however you wish.

Answer (score -1):

you can use date formatter code:

```objc
NSString *myString = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"; 
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```